# Компиляция dash

Tags: linux, c

Потребовалось скомпилировать dash, скачал исходники отсюда http://git.kernel.org/cgit/utils/dash/dash.git
И делаю в каталоге репозитория `./configure --help`, но файла `configure` как оказалось нет, в корне репозитория есть следующие файлы и директории: `autogen.sh ChangeLog.O COPYING src ChangeLog configure.ac Makefile.am`
А также в `src` есть `Makefile.am`
Я так понимаю мне нужно каким-то образом сгенерировать `configure` при помощи Automake
Как это сделать?

Comment: `autoconf`, он сгенерирует `configure`. https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/84/Autoconf-automake-process.svg/644px-Autoconf-automake-process.svg.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в [корне хранилища](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/utils/dash/dash.git/tree/) есть ровно один исполняемый файл — `autogen.sh`. вот его и надо запустить:

```
$ ./autogen.sh
```

в результате будет сгенерирован (в том числе и) файл `confrigure`.

ну а дальше вы уже знаете, что делать.